# How to export findbugs results from Eclipse findbugs plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, findbugs

I have findbugs plugin for eclipse which when run on my project will show results in Bugs explorer clubbed by the type of bug.

I need to be able to do two things:

- Export all these to excel sheet
- Find out the bugs reported in a set of files (and be able to do it recursively w/o running for whole project and exporting and finding out the classes to be modified.

Any suggestions?

FYI, I am using MyEclipse v 6.0.1 and FindBugs 1.3.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Findbugs dumps its results into an XML file in your workspace's .metadata folder. Look for the subfolder that's named something like findbugs.

You can also download a standalone version of Findbugs that will save the results wherever you like.

Once you have the results file, you might be able to import from XML to Excel and filter there. Alternatively, you can use XSLT to transform to several CSV files and open them in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with findbugs some versions ago.

I updated the plugin today to version 1.3.8 and found out that you can now export and even import reports as XML directly.

All you have to do is right-click on a project either in the package explorer or in the findbugs "Bug explorer" and select "Findbugs->Save XML" or "Findbugs->Load XML".

Finely a proper export and import functionality for a fantastic tool.

Btw, I use Eclipse 3.3.2.